# Build v-for src image

Tags: vue.js

I'm doing a VUE 3 project and I have problems with v-for src image. I have the next code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="title">Últimas incorporaciones</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div
        class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"
        v-for="pet in pets"
        :key="pet.nombre"
      >
        <article class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              v-bind:src="'../assets/pets/' + pet.imatge"
              alt="Thor"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-main">
              <!-- <h3 class="card-title">{{ pet.nombre }}</h3> -->
              <h3 class="card-title">{{ pet.nombre }}</h3>
              <p class="card-text">{{ pet.ciudad }}</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="card-icons">
              <li>
                <img
                  class="card-icon"
                  src="../assets/icons/icon_cat.svg"
                  alt="Gato"
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  class="card-icon"
                  src="../assets/icons/icon_male.svg"
                  alt="Macho"
                />
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want a v-for to show the images to each card. The pet.nombre and pet.ciudad is working good, but pet.image not.

My script is like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "PetList",
  data() {
    return {
      pets: [
        {
          nombre: "Thor",
          ciudad: "Barcelona",
          imatge: "thor.png",
        },
     };
   },
};
```

How can I show the images with this code?

Comment: What do you have in the image key? By the way, in you script you have imatge instead of image, maybe thats why.

Comment: How can you will do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<img class="card-img-top"
     :src="`../assets/pets/${pet.image}`"
     :alt="pet.nombre"
/>
```

Comment: I used your code but is not working. The url is correct but I don't know why is not working. I can't see the image

Comment: Is there any error on the console? If you paste the URL in your browser you see the image?

Comment: There's no error in console. Only this: [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
​ re-render

Comment: The image is in assets/pets. The urls is correct.

Comment: In element-console I can see: <img class="card-img-top" src="@/assets/pets/undefined" alt="Thor" data-v-c4122c46="">

Comment: The key of your collection is image or imatge ?